# Elpy: how to stop the underlying RPC process?

Tags: python, process, elpy

Whenever `elpy-mode` is activated upon visiting a python file, I see a `py.exe` executable start, with a subtree of processes. This should be the [remote procedure call](https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts.html#the-rpc-process) (thanks @al0 for the explanation). It's what Elpy uses to check syntax, documentation, etc. Just to be clear I'm not speaking of the Python interpreter, started with `run-python`.

After I kill the buffer with the python code and `elpy-mode`, I see that the spanned RPC process and its tree are still alive. This happens even if I don't have any buffers, open or buried, with `elpy-mode`.

I don't quite see the point of the RPC remaining alive. Is this by design? Is there a command or function to kill it? At the moment I must open the task manager to kill it.

Comment: Presumably this is the [rpc](https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts.html#the-rpc-process). I only see restart, not kill in the docs. Is it just alive or actually running?

Comment: Indeed it is, I'll edit my question to mention this. From what I see it is only alive; but it does use RAM, which in some cases would be precious to have available for something else.

Comment: @al0 Thank you for the implicit suggestion. The command `elpy-rpc-restart` kills the rpc, and it restarts it – but only if the elpy buffer still exists. So a solution is to first kill the buffer and *then* call `M-x elpy-rpc-restart`. Maybe this can be automated in some hook.
Please feel free to write your suggestion as a solution.

Comment: It would be normal for there to be a buffer (perhaps hidden) associated with the process.  Have a look at `M-x list-processes`

Comment: @phils You're right. There's an invisible buffer called `elpy-rpc`. Killing that buffer also kills the process. Thank you very much.